# mongoose OR operator in schema definition type

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Does mongoose support oneOf schemas similar to oneOf in JSON schema? Below is what i want to achieve

```
   new Schema({
     components: [{
      prop1: String,
      prop2: Number
     } | {
      prop3: Number
     }]
    });
```

I am ruling out MIXED as i do not want to allow anything, intead allow only one of 2 definitions but not anything.

Comment: Mongoose has [Discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) to deal with different representations of schema. Scroll down the page to [Embedded Discriminators in Arrays](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html#embedded-discriminators-in-arrays)

Comment: I was thinking the same as @NeillLunn, maybe discriminators are ok. Anyway, I suppose you can null the prop (if the schema will have a limited number of adicional props), and then, it will not appear inside the schema (it´s not the best but could work)